# How to recover important files after accidentally deleting /etc folder on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, crash

I am in desparate situation. I am/was running ubuntu on virtualbox on windows as host.

I accidentally deleted /etc folder. I have some files which are months of hard work. How can i retrieve them? I tried drag and drop, usb mounting, connecting to internet to share the files . Nothing worked. PLease please please help.

Comment: Specifically, are you trying to recove the contents of /etc, or are you trying to recover personal files that you had in /home?

Answer (score 3):

**As soon as possible** uncleanly turn off the VM and do nothing that would suppose a write to its disk (don't ever turn it on again).

Then you could use something like [photorec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the VM disk image.

Comment: Thank  you for your responses. Hard times brings the best brains together. 

i simply created a fresh installation of ubuntu Vm, added that to SATA , prioritized cd drive boot order
but the important part is to start the fresh copy of vm and choose try ubuntu, instead of install. This way u can get access to all the files from the trial version. 
No complicated process at all 

Only issue is somehow transferring the data out of the trial version. I basically logged into my cloud data store and dropped all my files there. All done. PHEW. That was a lesson. Always back up data from VM